# sqllite3 data delete from table in python

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter, tkinter-entry

im trying to delete a specific record where username and bookname should match and that record should be delete from the database. the code is working but data inside database is not deleted . im taking the book name nad username from entry field in tkinter. then finding that record and deleting it from db. i tried to go through many doc and diff code. i tried many diff method but none worked for me

```
con=sqlite3.Connection("Booking")
cur=con.cursor()
cur.execute("create table if not exists Booking(username varchar(20),address varchar(56),mob number(10),qty number(2),Book varchar(50))")
def sdw():
            te = Tk()
            te.geometry("250x300")
            L1 = Label(text="User Name").grid(row=1, column=0)
            E1 = Entry(te)
            E1.grid(row=1, column=2)
            L5 = Label(text="book name").grid(row=5, column=0)
            E5 = Entry(te)
            E5.grid(row=5, column=2)
            def db():
                print("gh")
        
                if os.path.isfile(E1.get()):
                    
                    st="DELETE  from Booking where username='%s' and Book='%s'"%(E1.get(),E5.get())
                    cur.execute("select * from Booking where username=?", (E1.get(),))
                    a = cur.fetchall()
                    messagebox.showinfo('Find', a)
                    cur.execute(st)
                    
                    messagebox.showinfo('Find', "all booking deleted")
                    te.destroy()
                    os.system("library.py")
        
                else:
                    messagebox.showinfo("ERROR","username invalid")
            b161 = Button(text="search booking", command=db)
            b161.place(x=100, y=100)
            te.mainloop()
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you're committing any changes to the database. Are you aware that you need to do that?  You also seem to be selecting on the item before deleting it.

Comment: Delete is a DML statement, means it requires you to commit the change, so you have to say. `con.commit()` to save the changes.

Comment: @CoolCloud  i tried that con.comit() it didnt worked at all . i read that in a doc about it but idk y code run but didnt made any change to db

Comment: You have to say `commit()` after executing the `delete` statement

Comment: @CoolCloud thanks buddy,for your help. i used conn insted of con wrong , as i read here https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-python/delete/   , idk y  but it showed me conn